# Font-size Form Select Options in Android - Ionic

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework, chromium

Is there any way to style font size of ionic form select in Android? Popup is handled by the browser, I am wondering is there is any way to customize it.

```
<select>
      <option>Blue</option>
      <option selected>Green</option>
      <option>Red</option>
    </select>
```

Thank you

Comment: what about tag selector like `select{font-size:25px;}`

Comment: Actually it is a browser managed component. So any edit to style on select option won't give any change (unless we use it with ionic serve on browser).

According to ionic doc: "the default behavior on how to select one of the options is still managed by the browser"